# Instruments cannot attach an ios device?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

[instruments snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuzkO.png)

[system.log when I select ***Xcode -> Debug -> Attach to process***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLk86.jpg)

and the ***Attach to process*** is null.

- Xcode: 7.1
- Mac: OSX El Capitan
- Iphone: iOS 9.1

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was to:

```
- unplug my phone
- reboot it
- quit Xcode and instruments
- plug my phone in again
- opened Xcode and launched instruments and it worked.
```

Answer (score 1):

[I find the answer](https://discuss.appium.io/t/failed-to-start-instruments-daemon-on-p-v-iphone-5s-7-1-2-the-service-is-invalid/4530/2).

Follow this steps:

> Open the **Xcode** than select select the **windows>organizer** select the device and clear the Console and device logs. After above steps instruments have detected the device.